# Set of bijective operators open in $L(X,X)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $U=\{T \in L(X,X)$ s.t. $T$ bijective $\}$. $(X,||.||)$ be a normed $\mathbb R$ vector space.
Is it true that $U$ is open in $L(X,X)$?
Could someone explain me why it is true/not true?

Comment: $L(X,X) =$ linear continuous?

Comment: yes, exactly! Sorry, I didn't mention it in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $U$ is open.

We denote operator-norm on $L(X,X)$  also by $||.||$.

Let $T_0 \in U$ and $T \in L(X,X)$ and suppose that

(1)  $||T-T_0||< \frac{1}{||T_0^{-1}||}$.

We want to show that $T \in U$. To this end verify that

(2) $T=T_0(I-T_0^{-1}(T_0-T))$.

The operator $I-T_0^{-1}(T_0-T)$ is invertible, since (1) holds (Neumann- Series !). Hence, by (2), $T$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What does here $I$ exactly mean? Is it the Identity-function? 
And isn't in general $||T^{-1}||  = ||T||^{-1}$?

Comment: @TigerLa, (1) Yes, $I =$ identity. (2) False: consider a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1/2$, $2$.

Comment: But isn't it possible that $1/||T_0^{-1}||$ in (1) could be infinite?

Comment: No. If $A \in L(X,X)$, then $||A||=0$ if and only if $A=0$. We have $T_0^{-1} \ne 0$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! Thanks @Fred for your help!

Comment: Don't we need $X$ to be Banach for the Neumann Series to converge? @Fred

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove first that $B(I,1)\subset U$. Given $I+H\in B(I,1)$, write $(I+H)^{-1}$ as a power series remembering the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Will try to prove it with it.